# Hibernate - Retrieve objects with null FK

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Is it possible to fetch only some fields from objects with null foreign keys using Hibernate?

I have an entity `Cccg` with references to other tables, such as `unidadMedida`. I want to fetch some fields from `Cccgs` from the database, including `id_unidadMedida` either if this field `id_unidadMedida` is null or not. I can get the objects if I fetch the whole object, **but I only want to get some fields**. The problem is that Hibernate seems to convert the HQL, of the form:

```
select a.idnCccg, a.id_unidadMedida ... where (to_date('01/01/2014 00:00:00','dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') <= a.fecFinVigencia or a.fecFinVigencia is NULL) a.fechaBajaLogica is NULL
```

into a query that compares the value of the field with `unidadMedida`'s primary key.

```
select ... from PROG_TCCCG cccg0_, PROG_TUNIDAD_MEDIDA unidadmedi_ where cccg0_.IDN_UNIMED=unidadmedi_.IDN_UNIDAD_MEDIDA and ...
```

Since in SQL any comparison with null returns false, `cccg0_.IDN_UNIMED=unidadmedi_.IDN_UNIDAD_MEDIDA` will always evaluate to false and there is no way of fetching entries with null `unidadMedida`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: did you try left join and with clause?

Comment: no, why? What I want is to avoid joins with unidadMedida.

Comment: left join brings results even if the fk is null